# Ordering a Google Sheet based on a column

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Im using the Google Sheets API to call a sheet. I can successfully ingest the data and get it to appear in browser. Right now its coming in the order of the sheet, ie row 1, 2, 3, 4.

I want to change the order when queried. Looked at the docs and it seems I am supposed to use the sortSpecs option, but its not changing the order. It just keeps coming in based on the Sheet row order. Heres the code:

```
    function getSheetData() {
    gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: 'sheetID',
          range: 'Sheet!A2:I',
          sortSpecs: [
              {
                "dimensionIndex": 5,
                "sortOrder": "DESCENDING"
              },
            ]
        }).then(function(response) {
          var range = response.result;
          if (range.values.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
                var row            = range.values[i];
                var name           = row[0];
                var bio            = row[1];
                var site           = row[2];
                var title          = row[3];
                var description    = row[4];
                var location       = row[5];
                var time           = row[6];
                var slug           = row[7];
    });
  }
```

This is all coming in vanilla javascript. I run this function after I have successfully connected to the API, so it seems all is setup correctly from an API perspective. I just need to maniupulate the order based on a column value.

Comment: `sortSpecs` is used at the method of spreadsheets.batchUpdate. This cannot be used at the method of spreadsheets.values.get. The reason of your issue is this. If you want to retrieve the sorted values of Spreadsheet, at first, sort with spreadsheets.batchUpdate. As the next step, retrieve the sorted values with spreadsheets.values.get. But when `sortSpecs` is used, the values of Spreadsheet are actually sorted. I'm not sure whether this is the result you want. So I posted this as a comment. How about this?

Answer (score 0):

As Tanaike said, you cannot sort values with [spreadsheet.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get). You should use [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate).

Following Tanaike's comment, if you don't want the values of your sheet to get sorted, as a workaround you can first [make a copy of your sheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo), then call [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) to the newly created sheet to sort the data, then retrieve the sorted values from the new sheet with [spreadsheet.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) and finally delete the sheet you copied with [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet#delete_a_sheet).